# DOMPDF PDF file fails to open in Adobe when using basic HTML tags

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf, html-to-pdf

I am trying to generate some VERY simple PDFs based on some simple HTML output. My basic structure of expected output is:

```
Category Name 1
 [Product Image 1] Product Name 1
 [Product Image 2] Product Name 2
Category Name 2
 [Product Image 3] Product Name 3
```

I can generate some very basic PDFs fine (I'm using DOMPDF 0.5) from my HTML. For example, a PDF with the content 'test' exports fine.

However, as soon as I try to insert even the slightest HTML markup, the PDF exports but no longer opens in Adobe Acrobat, instead giving the error:

> 'Adobe Reader could not open
>   filename.pdf because it is either not
>   a supported file type or because the
>   file has been damaged (for example, it
>   was sent as an email attachment and
>   wasn't correctly decoded).

Has anyone had a similar problem? It seems sometimes I can get the file to open with tags like `<h1>test</h1>` but generating a file with `<p>pargaraph</p>` would fail. Is there any solution or are there any better alternatives to using DOMPDF (provided the solution can be used on a shared hosting environment).

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure there is no output before the HTML, and you call `exit` (or similar) after?

Comment: Could you provide the HTML source code ? The error seems to be outputted in the PDF document itself, open it with notepad to see the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your PHP version. It doesn't support "set_magic_quotes_runtime", and your PDFs are basically being overwritten with php error.

You can either suppress PHP error or put "@" in front of calls to set_magic_quotes_runtime in lib/class.pdf.php